# Mechanism to identify users that are (not) worth the effort (private white/black list?)

Tags: feature-request, users

I'm seeing an increasingly list of vague questions where my comments asking for clarifications ("do you want to do X?") are dismissed angrily in terms like "my question is clear, don't leave comments if you can't help" (and no reference to X). Sometimes I check the user history and find out I had the same problem in previous questions from the same user. It's not positive for anyone that next time he posts a similar vague question I leave another comment but I just can't remember all the user names.

It'd be cool if I had a way to tag the user or attach a note to its profile or something similar. I don't mean banning anyone or making those flags public, it'd be something private and merely for personal reference. I'm also not talking about the question itself (which can handled with the usual tools if it's actually not answerable).

Perhaps it's possible to solve it in more general terms and implement personal white/black lists which would also help to spot users who make great questions and deserve attention.

What do you thing about it?

Comment: Why not let us know when a user is being particularly bad at taking advice? A moderator message might get some of the more good-faith users to pay attention, failing which we can give them a much-needed break from the site (assuming they haven't hit the block yet/won't do so anytime soon).

Comment: That solves the problem for you, but the vague question still remains. You are helping with comments asking for clarification, even if the request gets rebuffed.

Comment: There is a mechanism in place for this, and it's visible for *all* users: comment -> down vote -> close.

Comment: For whitelisting, see StackEye and Stack User Filter on stackapps.com (disclosure: I wrote (and use) the latter one).

Comment: All those are good points. My main concern is to avoid starting a flame in the user's next question; perhaps some other regular has the ability to gather the missing information.

Comment: Out of curiosity... My question does not show any research effort, is unclear or it's just not useful? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel your pain, but the problem I see with a formal mechanism is that it would encourage people to write off others *permanently* because, as we all know, people do not change.

That's sometimes true (people don't change), but also I think "dismissed angrily" paranoid type reactions are often just a *stage* certain people go through as their experience with technical forums (boards, exchanges, whatever) increases.  I certainly remember taking things the wrong way when I first started using a programming board regularly (fortunately, before S.O. existed -- my head is well sorted now, I think).  It was only when I started answering more questions than I asked that I realized how hard it can be to remain concise but not seem like like a jerk to someone unacquainted.

Occasionally I've ending up doing this:

> I'm not trying to belittle or dismiss you.  I'm trying to *help*.  Don't confuse a friend for an enemy, calm down, and re-read what I've written with that in mind. :)

This doesn't always work, but it does have a better than 50% success rate in my experience.   All of sudden someone who was antagonistic and paranoid is *thanking you and apologizing*.  Then you get that warm feeling from having turned someone's life around a little bit.

Keep in mind that people who are genuine time-wasters and intentionally abusing a system will tend to create new accounts.  They may then keep one with a minimal amount of rep to do stuff like close voting, etc.

Comment: Sometimes simple solutions work. Thank you for you insight (and an awesome canned comment I'll definitively plagiarise).

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for *just* you to have this.

If a user is terribly bad and keeps on asking unclear questions, posts bad answers, etc., we downvote, close the question, delete answer, comment, etc. In this way, it doesn't only benefit you, it also benefits all of us.

Answer (score 7):

You really shouldn't need to do this, and I don't approve of it at all, since we're supposed to focus on the question content rather than the user, but there is a userscript called [StackPlonk](https://stackapps.com/questions/2912/stackplonk-plonk-users-you-dont-want-to-help-anymore) on [Stack Apps](//stackapps.com) that allows you to "plonk" a user, which does this:

[image: Image for StackPlonk]

You set it on their profile page, and you can "unplonk" them at any time in the same way.

Keep in mind that all you're doing here is ignoring a user for no one's benefit but your own: you could try to help the user, which might improve their questions, or, if they're *really* on the wrong path, let a moderator take care of them.

You're effectively just ignoring the problem, which doesn't make it go away for anyone but you.

Again, you **really** shouldn't do this, but if you *must*...

Comment: Of course, I would never use this but it does address a problem. Thanks for sharing.